# Are all the virtual cyclic subgroups of $PSL(2,\mathbb{R})$ elementary?

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups, hyperbolic-geometry

Let  $\Gamma$ a virtual cyclic subgroup of $PSL(2,\mathbb{R})$, i.e. there are $\Lambda \leq \Gamma$ with $\Lambda$ cyclic of finite index. ¿Is $\Gamma$ elementary?, where elementary means that there are $z\in \mathbb{H}\cup \partial \mathbb{H}$ such that $|\Gamma \cdot z|<\infty$.

I think the answer is not, but I don't know how to construct virtual cyclic subgroups of $PSL(2,\mathbb{R})$.   So, I tried to prove it.  Suppose that $\Lambda = \big<h \big>$, with $ h \in PSL(2, \mathbb{R})$. Since the index of $\Lambda$ is finite we can choose the representatives of the lateral classes as $g_1, \ldots, g_k$, then for all $g \in \Gamma$ there are $i \in \{1,\ldots,k\}$   such that $g^{-1}\circ g_i\in \Lambda$, and since $\Lambda $ is cyclic $g^{-1}\circ g_i= h^{n_i}$. I think that the only possible $z\in \mathbb{H} \cup \partial\mathbb{H}$ with finite $\Gamma$-orbit must be a $z_0 \in Fix(h)$.

Comment: It is "elementary", not "elemental." Try to prove the claim for cyclic groups first. What is your reason to doubt it?

Comment: Thanks. For cyclic groups is true,  because if $z_0$ is a fixed point of $h$, then $z_0$ is a fixed point of $h^{n}$ for all $n$, so the orbit of $z_0$ is finite.   Now, for virtual cyclic groups, given $g \in \Gamma$ there are $g_i$ with $i=1,..., k$ such that $g_i^{-1}\circ g = h^{n}$, I don't see how to use this to prove that the orbit of $z_0$ must be finite

Comment: Now use the definition of a finite index subgroup.